# How to download files from a database query with Zend Framework?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have a list of URLs stored in a database and I'm using Zend Framework to access that. The real question is. Is there a way to create a controller for download these URLs automatically whitin Zend Framework? Please help me. I need it

Comment: yes there is. You need to provide more details.

Comment: The URLs are stored in a local database using xampp, then I acces to that data through de controller and the model of Zend Framework. I want to download that list of URLs using some kind of controller, function, or php code that allow me to do this automatically.